# How to convert a whole ROW in a SEQ from a decimal to a float, and then back again?

Tags: f#

How do I convert a whole Row in a sequence from a decimal to a float, delete missing values or nan values, and then turn those same values back into decimals all in the same function.

Any suggestions?

By row I mean the row you select when you create a type from a CSV Provider.

```
type IncomeCsv = CsvProvider<IncomeCsvFile>
IncomeCsv.GetSample().Rows
|> Seq.filter (fun row -> row.State = "TX")
|> List.ofSeq
```

For one observation of TX, I am getting these values:

```
[(TX, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)]
```

This is an example of one observation from many in a SEQUENCE. I need to filter this specific observation out by using the function described above.

I have tried using Double.Is.NaN, but for some reason it is not working.

```
|> Seq.filter (fun element -> not (Double.IsNaN element))
```

I am getting this error:

```
  Practice2.fsx(39,53): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have 
     type
  'float'    
     but here has type
  'CsvProvider<...>.Row'
```

Comment: What is a `Row`? Can you provide a more concrete example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at both the [Csv type provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) and the [Csv file parser documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html). For example you can directly apply `Filter` and `Map` on the Csv provided type, to transform your data. In that case you would operate on the type directly (not its `Row`, e.g. on CsvFile.GetSample()). Also, the csv file parses is better suited for malformed data. There might are option to specify the schema and type directly, as well deal with missing values.

You can of course filter out `nan` and cast float to decimal in the usual way as well (this operates on CsvProvider.Row):

```
data 
|> Seq.filter (fun x -> not  (Double.IsNaN(x.Income)))
|> Seq.map (fun x -> (x.Id, x.State, decimal x.Income))
//val it : seq<int * string * decimal> =seq [(40, "TX", 2000.1M); (15, "TX", 3000M)]
```

The data I used:

> Id,State,Income
>   40,TX,2000.1
>   48,MO,#N/A
>   15,TX,3000
>   78,TN,
>   41,VT,

Comment: but besides the nan in that row, all the other rows are decimals, so I need to turn them into floats in order to call "Double.IsNaN". Can I just do this: `|> Seq.map (fun x -> float x.Income)` ? Before what you have above?

Comment: Yes, you can cast to `float` that way. You have a couple of options to deal with this, you could use the csv parser to actually transform the data before, you could specify the schema, or, as there is no `NaN` in decimals, you could use a nullable decimal. There are other file parsing libraries, like `FileHelpers` as well